PHONETICALLY, is a language without vowel possible? How many CONTRASTS can our vocal system make?
***** Phonetically, not phonologically
***** Exclude sign languages
I read it on Quora that it is possible for a language without phonemic vowel, but impossible without vowel phonetically.
Is it possible to make a sound with our mouth open without any vowel? If no, language without vowel = language with our mouth shut.
Possible contrasts I think of (the language would be acoustically more "musical" than "linguistic"):

Tones -- eg. ConLang solresol
Length Contrast (rhythm)-- long VS short like morse code
Pulmonic ingressive? Something like pig snort?
Consonant -- how many of them? [m̩] is the only pulmonic consonant I can think of
Some non-pulmonic consonants (some clicks?)
Loudness

Not sure if I am correct. What else is possible?

A language without phonetic vowels? While that may theoretically be physiologically possible, we can categorically say that no such human language has ever existed. Every language ever spoken has vowels. Some languages – most famously Nuxalk – have words without vowels, but they do still employ vowels in general. If you don’t syllabic sonorants like [r̩ l̩ n̩ m̩ ŋ̩ z̩ ɹ̩] as vowels, even though they form syllable peaks in many languages, then the theoretical likelihood rises… but still only in theory.

You may be interested in an art form named Human beat box; but this is not of linguistic relevance AFAIK.

@Janus Bahs Jacquet I am thinking [m̩] is different from other "syllabic consonants" because it can be truly syllabic without a vowel phonetically. I wonder if [n̩][ŋ̩] are the same. The others are impossible.

All of the phones I gave are possible as pure syllable peaks with any additional vowels; there is nothing impossible about any of them. American English burr is phonetically often [bɹ̩ʷː], Mandarin 四 sì is often [sz̩˥˩]. [z̩ ɹ̩] have enough friction to create noise; but [l̩ n̩ ŋ̩ m̩] all allow the air to pass through without any constriction narrow enough to create any noise and are thus all ‘vowels’. [l̩] arguably has less airflow restriction than a very high, very front [i], even.

@Janus Bahs Jacquet If they are vowels, does roundness, height and backness affect them?

Roundedness certainly does – there are languages that distinguish [l̩] and [l̩ʷ] or [m̩] and [m̩ʷ], for example. Height and/or backness is arguably relevant in [l̩] vs [ɫ̩], but of course height and backness cannot apply when the air flows through the nasal cavity. If you restrict the definition and require that at least some of the air must escape through the mouth, then the nasals are not vowels; but such a restriction is not universal. The line between ‘vowel’ and ‘not vowel’ is somewhat fuzzy in places.

[Note: In the first comment, “If you don’t syllabic sonorants” should of course be “If you count syllabic sonorants”.]
